# JNI method not invoked on centos7

Tags: java-native-interface

I have a Java code ServiceTest.java that invokes JNI code buildCache() to build the cache. This codes compiled and exceuted correctly on Ubuntu; however, on centos I compiled and exceuted and got this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.test.app.ServiceTest.buildCache()V
    at com.test.app.ServiceTest.buildCache(Native Method)
    at com.test.app.ServiceTest.<init>(ServiceTest.java:15)
    at com.test.app.ServiceTest.main(ServiceTest.java:47)
```

Looks like, it was able to load the so file, but it is not able to invoke the method.

ServiceTest.java

```
public class ServiceTest{


static {
        System.loadLibrary("cacheService");
    }

 public ServiceTest() {
        buildCache();
    }

 private native void buildCache();
}
```

libcacheService.so is placed in /usr/local/lib64. I have gcc 9 and jdk 1.8
and have set LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/ and export $LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Any idea on how to debug?

---

```
              ******Adding below simple testcode******
```

---

1.

```
public class Test{


    static {
     System.loadLibrary("greet");
    }

    Test(){
    }

    public static void main(String...s){
      Test t = new Test();
      System.out.println(t.greetings());
    }
    private native String greetings();
}
```

2. javah Test -> Test.h

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h> /* Header for class Test */

#ifndef _Included_Test
#define _Included_Test
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     Test
 * Method:    greetings
 * Signature: ()Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_Test_greetings
(JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

3. Greetings.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include "Test.h"
using namespace std;

class Test{

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_Test_greetings(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObject){
   jstring result = env->NewStringUTF("hi from JNI"); 
   return result;
 }  

};
```

4. `g++ --std=c++17 -g -I$JAVA_HOME/include -I$JAVA_HOME/include/linux -fPIC -shared -o greetings.so Greetings.cpp`
5. `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Djava.library.path=/lib64 Test`
6. again same issue

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Test.greetings()Ljava/lang/String;
    at Test.greetings(Native Method)
    at Test.main(Test.java:13)

With same GCC 9 and jdk 1.8

Comment: Your example is incorrect and incomplete: `System.loadLibrary("greet")` loads a `libgreet.so` yet you create a `greetings.so` You also do not show where this `greetings.so` is copied to. Furthermore, you're not supposed to wrap `Java_Test_greetings` in a class definition. JNI expects toplevel functions. You can verify the contents of your `.so` with the `nm` command. It should show `Java_Test_greetings` without any decorations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Greetings.cpp` should not include `class Test`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include "Test.h"
using namespace std;

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_Test_greetings(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObject){
   jstring result = env->NewStringUTF("hi from JNI"); 
   return result;
 }
```

Then, the Java statement `System.loadLibrary("greet");` expects to find a `libgreet.so` in its `java.library.path`, so compile it as follows:

```
g++ --std=c++17 -g -I$JAVA_HOME/include -I$JAVA_HOME/include/linux -fPIC -shared -o libgreet.so Greetings.cpp
```

Next, verify that the symbol is named *exactly* like the function, ie `nm libgreet.so | grep Java_Test_greetings` should produce output like the following:

```
0000000000000f20 T _Java_Test_greetings
```

Finally, run your Java program with the correct `java.library.path`.

Comment: Thanks the actual problem was with class Test in the Greetings.cpp

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that native library does not define a method that matches the signature of the Java `native` method; i.e. method name or signature in the JNI code is wrong ... or maybe it isn't a JNI native library at all.

Comment: I wrote this library. I checked the point you're mentioning the code and GCC and JDK versions are same except for the OS

Comment: I cannot take this any further from the information you have provided.  But the message definitely means that there is a mismatch between the Java code and the native library.

Comment: What do you mean by "except for the OS"?

Comment: Hi Stephen I have update the original post with a simple testcase it has the same issue.

Comment: The sample code I wrote tested on Ubuntu and it is giving the same error :(

Comment: Which is interesting.  Perhaps you did something differently in the first instance to get this to work on Ubuntu?  Perhaps you need to figure out what that was?  An can't try this now but I will give it a go this evening.

Comment: Thanks Stephen for your time